# Killing one Enemy causes every enemy to disappear - C# Unity

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with a game that I'm creating in Unity. The player controls a character that is getting attacked by a horde of zombies. I've created a spawner for all the zombies and that works great, the only problem is that once the player kills one zombie all the zombies disappear from the gameworld. I've posted the enemy script that is attached to each zombie below. I can't work out why every zombie is destroyed instead of just the one that has been attacked. Any help would be great!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour {

public static float Damage = 10.0f;
public static float Health = 10.0f;

public Transform target;
public float Speed;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //Destroy the enemy if it's health reaches 0
    if(Health <= 0){
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Debug.Log ("Enemy Destroyed!");
    }

    //Constantly move the enemy towards the centre of the gamespace (where the base is)
    float step = Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
  }
}
```

The way the scene is set up is that I have an empty game object that contains a series of position objects and a spawner script that places the enemy sprite into the position object. This all seems to work fine but I can't find whats causing them to all disappear.

Comment: problem with instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have declared `Health` as a static variable.  This means `Health` will have the same value across all of your enemy instances. Declare health like this instead:

```
public float Health = 10.0f;
```

This way, each instantiated enemy will be able to have its own unique `Health` value.